# How to count the number of changes in ROW (R)

Tags: r, dataframe, count

```r
df <- data.frame(Num1=c(1,0,1,0,1), Num2=c(0,1,1,0,1), Num3=c(1,1,1,1,1), Num4=c(1,1,0,0,1), Num5=c(1,1,1,0,0))
```

I need to count how many times value changes in each row in r.
Thank you!

Comment: your question not clear , what value you mean it changes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a try ,

```r
df <- data.frame(Num1=c(1,0,1,0,1), 
                 Num2=c(0,1,1,0,1),
                 Num3=c(1,1,1,1,1),
                 Num4=c(1,1,0,0,1),
                 Num5=c(1,1,1,0,0))


df$n_changes <- apply(df , MARGIN = 1 , function(x) sum(abs(diff(x))))

df
#>   Num1 Num2 Num3 Num4 Num5 n_changes
#> 1    1    0    1    1    1         2
#> 2    0    1    1    1    1         1
#> 3    1    1    1    0    1         2
#> 4    0    0    1    0    0         2
#> 5    1    1    1    1    0         1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

```
rowSums(df[-1] != df[-ncol(df)])
[1] 2 1 2 2 1
```

ie first row there is a change from 1 to 0 then back to 1. so a total of 2 changes etc

Comment: Thank you - the code works on the example. One more question - my dataframe has 20 columns, and I need to check only columns [2:11] for the switches - what do I need to modify in your code to do so? Thank you so much!

Comment: @RNewbie set `df1 <- df[2:11]` then in the code above replace `df` with `df1`

Answer (score 0):

We may loop over the row with `apply` (`MARGIN=1`), then use `rle` (run-length-encoding), check the `lengths`

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) lengths(rle(x)))[1,]-1
[1] 2 1 2 2 1
```

Comment: You are right.  I was thinking about the actual number of changes.  (`-1`)